# Primary Key attribute name is different in Generic Repository Pattern

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, generic-programming

I have multiple tables in database and for each table the primary key is long and the id column name is not generic i.e. each table primary key column name is different.

For example:

- Table `Customer` has primary key as 'CustomerId'
- Table `Employee` has primary key as 'EmployeeId'

And same get represented in the domain model class

```
class Customer { public long CustomerId { get; set; } 

class Employee { public long EmployeeId { get; set; }
```

How do I refer in primary key to get values based on different primary key name.

```
public async Task<TEntity> GetById(int id)
{
    return await _dbContext.Set<TEntity>()
                .AsNoTracking()
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(e => e.**Id** == id);
}
```

`Id` can be `CustomerId` or `EmployeeId`

Comment: How would you expect this to work?  You have multiple issues here, the least of all of which is your dynamic predicate.  You are expecting back `TEntity` but you aren't specifying a generic type in.  How on earth would you expect to get back a generic type in this case?  And if you're at the point where you have to specify the type, you should use a predicate argument which would solve all your woes.

Comment: What's wrong with `dB.<TABLE>.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x=> x... = id)` let EF be free!

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what you actually want to do, I would consider renaming the properties in the class to Id, and then map them to the keys in the database in the model configuration instead:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntityType>().Property(k => k.Id).HasColumnName("CustomerId");

// ...
}
```

However, if you really want to stick with those properties, and still want to use generic methods to get them (god knows why), you would probably have to expose a func on some interface that you later can use for the comparison.

Perhaps something like this:

```
        // An interface that requires a func to match it's id
        public interface IExpressionKeyEntity
        {
            // A func that takes an int and returns true if it's a match
            // against the entity id
            Func<int, bool> HasMatchingId { get; }
        }
```

With the simplest implementation of:

```
        // A simple customer class that implements the interface
        public class Customer : IExpressionKeyEntity
        {
            // An id property that we don't know anything about from the outside
            public int CustomerId { get; set; }

            // A func that takes an id and returns true if it's a match against this entities id
            public Func<int, bool> HasMatchingId => comparisonEntityId => comparisonEntityId == CustomerId;
        }
```

And then use it with some minor changes to the GetById-method:

```
            // GetById now requires an IExpressionKeyEntity to be retrieved
            public async Task<TEntity> GetById<TEntity>(int id)
                where TEntity : IExpressionKeyEntity
            {
                // Return the first match based on our func
                return await _dbContext.Set<TEntity>()
                    .AsNoTracking()
                    .FirstOrDefault(q => q.HasMatchingId(id));
            }
```

I have a feeling that I've stumbled into some problems with Func and EF before, but this should technically work. Otherwise you'll have to dig in on the Expressions.

Answer (score 1):

So to use this generic pattern your logic is slightly flawed.  You will not be able to determine the name of the primary id field from the TEntity type without attributes and reflection.  A better idea would be to have your entities implement an Interface and then place a constraint on your generic.  Something along these lines

```
public interface IEntity {
    int id {get;set;}
}

public class Customer : IEntity {
    public int id {get; set;}
}
```

Then in your repository you can constrain the generics to the type of IEntity.
This will allow you to just query based on the id field for any IEntity type.

```
where TEntity: IEntity
```

Then you method works by just looking for the Id field that is defined int he interface

```
public async Task<TEntity> GetById(int id)
{
    //Since TEntity is an IEntity, it is guaranteed to have an id property
    return await _dbContext.Set<TEntity>()
                .AsNoTracking()
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(e => e.Id == id);
}
```

Comment: This won't work for multiple reasons.  One, there is no column mapping that will handle the id comparison and you are currently expecting the OP to make a schema change as such.  Second of all, there's no way to return `Task<TEntity>` per my comment on the OP's question. Lastly, this doesn't compile :)

Comment: They can return Task<TEntity> if it is specified at the class level. As for not compiling, I just typed this out on here and I was merely trying to point him in the right direction for implementing a repository pattern.  If he wasn't to use this generic pattern, he needs to change his db schema and based on the basic classes he posted, I assume now would be the right time to do that if he wants to go this route.

Comment: My point is that the question isn't answerable since the OP hasn't provided enough context.  That said, it is admirable to try to head them off at the pass if they're in a position to make a schema change, although that is often not the case.

Comment: I agree, but if that is the case, then he really can't implement a generic repository pattern on this as his types will not support it.

Comment: @DavidL,@bhmahler : The schema is already designed and in use and I was planning to bring generic pattern, because of lot of code repetition , so basically I cant change the schema.

Comment: @HafeezKhan `I can't change the schema` is a one way ticket to an unmaintaboe legacy system

Answer (score 0):

Firstly i get the shivers whenever i see someone implement a Repository Pattern over EF

However, my peace-of-mind aside. If you have standard and normalised Id naming you could use an interface

```
public interface IId
{
    public long Id {get;set;}        
}

// ...

class Customer : IId { public long ID{get;set;} ...}
class Employee : IId { public long ID{get;set;} ...}

public async Task<TEntity> GetById<TEntity>(int id) where TEntity : IId
{
    return await _dbContext.Set<TEntity>()
                .AsNoTracking()
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(e => e.Id == id);
}
```

Or you could use an expression

```
public static async Task<T> GetById<T>(this IQueryable<T> entities, Expression<Func<T, long>> propertySelector, long id)
{
   var member = propertySelector.Body as MemberExpression;

   var property = member.Member as PropertyInfo;
   var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));

   var expression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(Expression.Equal(Expression.Constant(id), Expression.Property(parameter, property)), parameter);

   return await entities.FirstOrDefaultAsync(expression);
}
```

**Disclaimer**, all this is totally untested, and no error checking

Comment: If the OP has to specify a property selector, they might as well just pass in an entire predicate and avoid a a dynamic expression.

Comment: While this is potentially more flexible than an interface constraint, there's still the issue of the OP's question being too vague to answer properly.  Without more details from the OP it is impossible to tell how they intend to actually call this which would significantly influence the answer (and probably demonstrate that it simply isn't possible based on what they've currently described).

Comment: @DavidL actually, at looking at the question again, I tend to fully agree, also there are bigger design  problems going on as well

Comment: @DavidL anyway expressions aside, toasted sandwiches for the win